# Non persistent Authentication cookie in a SPA AngularJS / Django REST

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, authentication, cookies

I have been wrestling with this issue for several hours:
I have a Single-Page Application written in Angular which communicates with a DjangoREST backend. I am trying to implement an auth fonction with session Cookies. The way I see it is:

1/ Show any unlogged visitor a login page

2/ Make a POST to url/login with the credentials

3/ Obtain a "sessionid" cookie and writing in a service that the user is logged

4/ Redirect vistor towards reserved content and used get & post to access contents with the cookie

The login endpoint is already set and works. When I make a post, I receive a HTTP 200 response with user info and a Set-Cookie, but subsequent calls do not contain the Cookie:

```
Request URL: ...
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:38
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:devinify1.herokuapp..
Origin:http://mobilevinify.herokuapp...
Referer:http://mobilevinify.herokuapp...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:felix@vinify.co
password:test
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:189
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Sat, 14 Dec 2013 20:45:14 GMT
Server:gunicorn/18.0
Set-Cookie:sessionid=ijz27zy655qn0cwmlnvr66609hsyvdub; expires=Sat, 28-Dec-2013 20:45:14 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Vary:Cookie
```

My code is a very simple adaptation of the angular-app example:
https://github.com/FelixLC/MobileWebApp/blob/master/app/scripts/security/security.js

I have tried this on localhost et on heroku. The server and the client are on different domains, CORS are allowed.
When I try to make calls, I receive an error from Django

```
TypeError at /vinibarwines/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'
```

Should I try to get this cookie and put it in the headers with angularJS?

You can try to login at http://mobilevinify.herokuapp.com/#/login with felix@vinify.co & test. Then Click on Vinibar, there is a 500 internal error on the GET request

Any help much appreciated
Felix

Comment: I've tried unsuccessfully to login cross domain with django rest, but I always end up using tokens instead. It's easy enough to implement. If you're interested I can post an answer.

Comment: Actually, I stumbled upon your github earlier! I tried your solution, but does it work when we refresh the page? I couldn't get your project to not unlogg me when refreshing

Comment: Yeah the seed project doesn't use cookies, check out the answer below I submitted for another guys similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full layout of how I actually do my authentication. [Django/Angular Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498317/user-authentication-in-django-rest-framework-angular-js-web-app/20500498#20500498). It's a pretty extensive response, I'm more than happy to answer further questions you might have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well. However, if I refresh or quit the app, all the angular part gets rebooted and the token is lost: I have to authenticate again. Do you think that there would be a workaround? Maybe hard writing the auth-token in the browser's cookie?

Comment: @FelixLC I just added persisted tokens to the seed, hope it is helpful.